# Resize makes things wrong

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I want to create a JInternalFrame with some components in it.

My aim is to design a bash console in Java.

My frame is made of 4 components:

- JTextArea included into a JScrollPane
- JLabel with the text "Cmd:"
- JTextField
- JButton with the text "Send"

And I have the following code:

```
Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
box.add(this.cmd_label);
box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
box.add(this.cmd_input);
box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
box.add(this.submit);
box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));

Box mainBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
mainBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
mainBox.add(this.result_scroll);
mainBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
mainBox.add(box);
mainBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
add(mainBox);
```

So when the frame has not been maximized, I have a correct look:

[image: Non-maximized frame]

But when I maximize it, all components are incorrectly located:

[image: Maximized frame]

So, here is my question: How can I set a weight to the components to fix their location every time, or, how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be better done with a `BorderLayout`.  In a BorderLayout, the component specified as the center component will expand to fill as much space as possible, and the other components will remain at their preferred sizes.

```
int hgap = 5;
int vgap = 5;
internalFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(hgap, vgap));
internalFrame.getContentPane().add(this.result_scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
bottomPanel.add(this.cmd_label);
bottomPanel.add(this.cmd_input);
bottomPanel.add(this.submit);
internalFrame.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Thanks it works but the JTextField no longer take the whole width. How can i do that?

Comment: use another `BorderLayout` for your bottomPanel :)

Comment: +1, I like this approach, that's what I thought of at my first glance of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here try this code, is this behaviour exceptable :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutExample
{
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LAYOUT EXAMPLE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        centerPanel.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
        JTextArea tarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        tarea.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY.darker());  
        tarea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        tarea.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);
        tarea.setLineWrap(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tarea);
        centerPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel footerPanel = new JPanel();
        footerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        footerPanel.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));       
        JLabel cmdLabel = new JLabel("Cmd : ");         
        JTextField tfield = new JTextField(10);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("SEND");

        footerPanel.add(cmdLabel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        footerPanel.add(tfield, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        buttonPanel.add(sendButton);
        footerPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        frame.getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(footerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new LayoutExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: AT START]

[image: WHEN MAXIMIZED]

Answer (score 1):

Base problem here is what I consider a bug in JTextField's max layout hint: it's unbounded in both horizontal *and* vertical dimension. The latter is pure nonsense for a component designed for showing a single line of text. To fix, subclass and let it return its pref for the height, like:

```
JTextField cmdInput = new JTextField() {

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        Dimension max = super.getMaximumSize();
        max.height = getPreferredSize().height;
        return max;
    }

};
```

As BoxLayout respects maxSize, the excess height now will be given to the top box only.

On the long run, consider switching to a third party manager which allows fine-tuning in a all-in-one-panel approach. Yeah, here comes my current favourite: MigLayout. Compare the following lines to all the nesting and border tricks above and have fun :-)

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap 3, debug", 
        "[][grow, fill][]", // 3 columns, middle column filled and allows growing
        "[grow, fill][]"); // two rows, first filled and allows growing

JComponent content = new JPanel(layout);
// the scrollPane in the first row spanning all columns
// and growing in both directions 
content.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(20, 20)), "span, grow");
// auto-wrapped to first column in second row
content.add(new JLabel("Cmd:"));
content.add(new JTextField());
content.add(new JButton("Submit"));
```

Comment: +1  for fixing Core-Javas components again ;-)  And for the LayoutManager: I can't really decide between MigLayout and DesignGridLayout...